# Can't access to the content of a ControlTemplate from code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Here is my XAML. The UserControl is named "Event"

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="eventStyle" TargetType="Thumb">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                    <Rectangle Name="rect" Fill="CadetBlue" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Canvas>
   <Thumb Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Name="MoveThumb" Style="{StaticResource eventStyle}" Cursor="SizeAll" DragDelta="MoveThumb_DragDelta" DragStarted="MoveThumb_DragStarted" DragCompleted="MoveThumb_DragCompleted" />
</Canvas>
```

And here is the code behind

```
var ev = new Event();
var rect = ev.Template.FindName("rect", ev) as Rectangle;
```

But it doesn't work : the "rect" variable is null. What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Ivan
There's no exception message. "rect" is still null, without exception.

Comment: When are you doing this? Are you sure the template has been applied?

Comment: I create this event from a class called Scheduler. When I click on a button, I create this event, add it to the scheduler's list of events and draw it. The code I use for the creation of the event are the two lines above.
The template is applied, because my rectangle has the color AliceBlue. What I want, is change the color according of the nature of the event. That's why I want to access the rectangle.

Answer (score 2):

The template you're defining is applied to the `Thumb` control, and not the `Event` control - that's why there's no `rect` control in `Event`'s template.

Since you're creating the `Event` control from another class, what you can do is expose the `MoveThumb` control as a property in `Event`'s code-behind, like this:

```
public Thumb TheThumb
{
    get { return MoveThumb; }
}
```

Then you can change your code to this:

```
var ev = new Event();
var rect = ev.TheThumb.Template.FindName("rect", ev.TheThumb) as Rectangle;
```

Better yet, you can expose the `rect` control as a property:

```
public Rectangle Rect
{
    get { return MoveThumb.Template.FindName("rect", MoveThumb) as Rectangle; }
}
```

and use it like this

```
var ev = new Event();
var rect = ev.Rect;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Did it the same way... but still null ! Both solutions gave null for my rect variable. Can't figure what's happening. I created a test project and it works... I don't understand

Comment: I've just noticed one thing : it works the second time ! If I start a debugging session, then I watch the value of rect, it is null the first time I stop on the breakpoint. But, in the same debugging session, rect is not null the second time I stop on the breakpoint ! WTF ?

Answer (score 1):

It returned **null** because the function **FindName("controlName",TemplatedParent)** expects a control on which the template is applied as the second parameter. From the code you've provided, I couldn't see when the template was applied to the control (**ev** used to the default template). Hence, the **rect** variable was null.

Try this

```
var rectangle = MoveThumb.Template.FindName("rect", MoveThumb) as Rectangle;
```

More information is available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613586.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworktemplate.findname.aspx)

Comment: Same thing. rect is still null... I don't understand

Comment: I have copied your code and checked my code using VS 2010/.Net 4. The rectangle instance is not null!!!!

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention : I create the event from another class. See comment above.